# How to add Kanji keyboard in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, japanese, kanji

I'm learning Japanese currently, and I want to be able to add the Kanji keyboard to Kubuntu so I'll be able to type with Hiragana characters. Anyone know how this is done? When I add a new Japanese layout I get to choose between Dvorak, Kana 86, Kana, Macintosh, OADG 109A, Sun type 6 and Sun type 7.

Comment: Have you already installed the Japanese language ?

Comment: Where would I do that?

Comment: According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769609/how-to-install-additional-languages-in-kubuntu-16-04-lts) you have install `language-selector-gnome` if you're using Kubuntu.

Comment: Just installed Japanese with language-selector-gnome

Comment: @Jonathan So does this mean you've got it working?  If not, take a look at this [web site](http://srobb.net/jpninpt.html) which talks about numerous Linux distributions, including Ubuntu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/791834/japanese-input-on-16-04-with-fcitx-and-mozc It's about the same operation. Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/929793/when-using-mozc-to-input-japanese-its-using-the-last-selected-keyboard-layout/929837?noredirect=1#comment1471481_929837 would help, I think.